# With hardlinks, does it matter which is which?

Tags: macos, filesystem

If I make replace duplicate files with hardlinks within my home (~) directory, I'm thinking it is completely irrelevant which of two files gets replaced.

Is this true, or is there some asymmetry that I am not aware of?

Answer (score 1):

No - hard links work like individual files. As long as you make the next link/copy in the correct folder/directory - you are good to go. When you cross a filesystem boundary - the link breaks automagically and it becomes a distinct file.

Comment: I'm not making another; I'm replacing one of two identical files.  I believe that it doesn't matter which file gets deleted and linked.  Just trying to make sure.

Comment: Yep @WGroleau  it doesn't matter. The link will exist in both places and there's no difference which is first. Good question - +1